# How to debug the android app in emulator/device on react native 0.62.0?

Tags: android, react-native

I have updated my react native app to version 0.62.0 from 0.59.0 some time ago. I am able to debug the app on ios simulator and device but not able to get the `in app developer menu` on android by pressing the command+m key for emulator and device (on shaking the device). While updating I skipped the code for Flipper which is a new debugging tool that comes by default with RN 0.62.0.
I am also not able to see the change in app when I run the app from Android Studio.

Is it not possible to use the shake gesture feature or debug the app without Flipper on Android ?

Comment: The developer menu is still available for 0.62 version you most likely forgot a step while updating your project

Comment: @MahdiN which step ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command from terminal, I set it up to a hotkey so I can do it quickly cause its annoying to have to shake your device anyway..

1. First time you need to do this to get device list and it will return a list of devices, choose the number for your device, something like "2663404d12057ece"

> adb devices

2. To open developer menu on device use command:

> adb -s YOUR_DEVICE_NUMBER shell input keyevent 82

Comment: I am not having device right now, how get developer options on emulator ?

Comment: It's the same procedure to get the options to show on emulator, just make sure the emulator is running when you type `adb devices`

Comment: @cschultz1272 this is a huge help to me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, `MainApplication.java` file contained this import statement `import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;` which is not needed. The BuildConfig.java should be pulled from `android/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/[your]/[package]/[name]/BuildConfig.java` instead, which is imported automatically when the project is build/synced in Android Studio.

After I remove the import statement I was able to see the developer menu and reload the app.